# Runtime error in java about selection sort

Tags: java, arrays, selection-sort

I have learnt selection sort, and i try to code it with java. But it has an error, i think it a runtime error. I don't know what to fix in my code.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int temp;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        int input=sc.nextInt();
        int [] carriage;
        carriage=new int[input];
        for(int i=0;i<input;i++)
        {
            number=sc.nextInt();
            carriage[i]=number;


        }
        int n=carriage.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;i<n;j++)
            {
                if(carriage[j]<carriage[i])
                {
                    temp=carriage[i];
                    carriage[i]=carriage[j];
                    carriage[j]=temp;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(carriage[i]+ " ");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *i think it a runtime error. I don't know what to fix*. You can start by adding the error to your answer. Also it might be worthwhile to take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `for(int j=i+1;i<n;j++)`  are you sure this is correct? I think it should be `for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)`

Comment: @CocoNess yeah man thanks alot hahaahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to sort the number of integer provided by user. Your code is having 2 errors. One in the for loop starting with i, the condition should be i

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int temp;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of integers to be sorted - ");
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        int[] carriage;
        carriage = new int[input];
        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the "+ i+1 +"number  - ");
            number = sc.nextInt();
            carriage[i] = number;
        }
        int n = carriage.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (carriage[j] < carriage[i]) {
                    temp = carriage[i];
                    carriage[i] = carriage[j];
                    carriage[j] = temp;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(carriage[i] + " ");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers